# Smarty + ajax unexpected identifier

Tags: javascript, ajax, smarty, sugarcrm, suitecrm

Working in SuiteCRM and having an issue with the following code ONLY on the server. This works correctly in my local environment:

```
function take_ticket(url, id) { 
    $.ajax({
        url: 'index.php?entryPoint=takeTicket',
        contentType: 'JSON',
        data: {
            'id': id
        },
        success: function(response){
            window.location = url;
            //alert(response);
        },
        error: function(response) {
            alert('Error');
        }
    });
    return false;
};
```

When run on the server, the console shows an unexpected identifier error and the code looks like this:

```
function take_ticket(url, id) ajax({
        url: 'index.php?entryPoint=takeTicket',
        contentType: 'JSON',
        data: {
            'id': id
        ,
        success: function(response)location = url;
            //alert(response);
        ,
        error: function(response) {
            alert('Error');
        }
    });
    return false;
};
```

It appears that the opening bracket, line break, and $. after the function declaration are being omitted. I also noticed random missing characters in the data and success objects. I've checked the encoding of the file on both my local repo and the server and both are UTF-8. The IIS app pool has been reset as well.

Any thoughts?